# Dockerfile Copy all files from app source code to container Workdir except one file

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, copy, containers

I would like to copy all files from app source code except one file named Jenkinsfile. I want to improve caching because I update Jenkinsfile continuously. What seems the most effective to you?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add filename to `.dockerignore` to exclude it from context (works for ADD and COPY commands as well).
More details [in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/#dockerignore-files).